# Show accepted terms and conditions on order confirmation

Tags: terms-and-conditions

One thing has been really bugging me about the Terms and Conditions system in Magento.

A person accepts the terms and conditions at checkout, for example they agree that the store is currently on holiday and their orer will be sent in two weeks time. Great!

The problem is, the customer then writes to us a week later going: "where is my order"? At that point, you can argue all you like that he accepted the terms and conditions at checkout, while he insists he never did. The point is: you can't prove it.

What needs to happen is: the order confirmation email that gets sent out to customers should indicate that they ticked the terms and conditions box. It should show either the full terms and conditions text, or just the "Condition Name" used in the backend, which we could make descriptive enough to make it clear what they agreed to.

I know it's a rather specific requirement so it's unlikely that it would be added if I ask the Magento team for it. Basically I am looking for a bit of code to add to the order confirmation email's template which will print any terms and conditions that have been agreed to at checkout.

A possible workaround would be to temporarily change the email template when there's any terms and conditions enabled. It's just not very convenient.

I haven't found any extensions for this and I don't have the skills to write the code myself. If anyone can think of a simple solution, your help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This one is also needed for forwarding personal data like email address to a shipping partner in EU due to GDPR restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone can think of a simple solution, your help would be appreciated.

Customer shouldn't need to confirm after a purchase, they've already agreed by using your website.

The terms and conditions should be clearly displayed on your website. Usually in the footer, easy to find - not just on the checkout page.

The way most merchants achieve this is to have a separate CMS page that clearly outlines all relevant points (shipping in your case).

In addition to having a CMS page, include a link in the order confirmation email linking back to the terms of your website.

-- I believe a FAQ questions would be also beneficial for your scenario.